# Questions on JBehave

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jbehave

I recently have implemented JBehave with webdriver for automation. I have few queries.

1. can JBehave store the results in DB after the suite is completed?
2. Can we modify the Jbehave report to display the buildnumber?
3. can we run webdriver tests to run from jbehave web runber.Example of etsy.com doesn't actually run the webdriver stories.
4. Can we integrate the results with web-runner. i.e instead of opening target/view.index.html , can we host it on any webserver along with web-runner.

Comment: Yes, for all your queries ! :), For fewthings you might need to write up your own utility functions !

Comment: May I know how to accomplish 1 and 2..

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question,

1) No, Not necessary at all.But you can write your own utility classes and call the methods for DB insertion as you wish. [Here The Official selenium Database access Docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html),But the DatabaseStorage interface is depreciated.

2) To make a templatable views , you need to [look at here](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/reporting-stories.html), the view generation can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for some of these things was to use continuous integration using Jenkins.

1. Create jenkins job as described here [Integration of jbehave with jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972696/integration-of-jbehave-with-jenkins)
2. The results are available for all the test runs until the runs are purged in jenkins (which is configurable).